# Printing even characters with strings in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = 'Abrakadabra'
for k in (len(s)):
  if (k%2==1):
    print(s[k])
```

This code doesn't work, what is the problem?

Comment: Use `range(len(s))` instead of `len(s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through int `(len(s))`
i think you're just simply missing the `range` function

```
s = 'Abrakadabra'
for k in range(len(s)):
  if k%2==1:
    print(s[k])
```

also much simlpler version is could be done with:

```
>>> s[1::2]
'baaar'
```

let's break it down:

```
s[1: :2]
^ ^ ^ ^
|-|-|-|--- string to use
  |-|-|--- index to start from (1 for even, zero or ' ' for odd)
    |-|--- index to stop at - space means "till the end"
      |----step to take - 2 for every second, 3 for every third and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over the `range` of `len(s)`

```
s = 'Abrakadabra'
for k in range(len(s)):
  if (k%2==1):
    print(s[k])
```

and even easier pythonic way is

```
print(s[1::2])
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) to iterate over: `for k in range(len(s)):`...

you could also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

```
s = 'Abrakadabra'

for i, x in enumerate(s):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print(x)
```